# Creating a class object by introducing values from a list

Tags: python, class, object, constructor

I have created a class named 'My_class', and created 4 objects (obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4) as follows.

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self, att1, att2, att3, att4, att5, att6):
        self.att1 = att1
        self.att2 = att2
        self.att3 = att3
        self.att4 = att4
        self.att5 = att5
        self.att6 = att6

    def __repr__(self):

        return "The values of the attributes are ({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.att1, self.att2, self.att3, self.att4,
                                                                                    self.att5, self.att6)

obj1 = My_class(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
print(obj1)

obj2 = My_class(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
print(obj2)

# Lets say that I have 3 lists and I want to create the objects from the values of the lists.

list3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
list4 = [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6]
list5 = [-10, -20, -30, -40, -50, -60]

obj3 = My_class(list3[0], list3[1], list3[2], list3[3], list3[4], list3[5])
print(obj3)

obj4 = My_class(list4[0], list4[1], list4[2], list4[3], list4[4], list4[5])
print(obj4)
```

The output of this code is:

```
The values of the attributes are (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
The values of the attributes are (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
The values of the attributes are (a, b, c, d, e, f)
The values of the attributes are (-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6)
```

I would like to create obj5 with the values of list5 using the following structure:

```
obj5 = My_class('introduce somehow the 6 values of list5 here without having to manually write them seperated by comas')
```

This is a simple example using 6 attributes. The idea is to have a compact and efficient way to do this in case there are many more attributes.

Thank you

Comment: `obj5 = My_class(*list5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
obj5 = My_class(*list5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Samwise wrote as a comment is correct. I just want to add that if you want to initialize a class by unpacking the list you might be doing something wrong.

Either way, if you want to do that, safer option is to create a special class method for that, like

```
@classmethod
def from_list(cls, l: list):
    # here you make sure that the length is ok etc
    return cls(*l)
```

And you use it like that

```
obj = My_class.from_list(l)
```

That's more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do at this time.

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        for i in range(0,len(args)):
            exec(f"self.att{i} = {args[i]}")
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)
```

Comment: `My_class("exit('pwned')")`

Comment: Such a concern depends on context, on who has access, and where the script will be used.